# Excel file (azure blob) does not download in chrome

Tags: excel, azure, azure-blob-storage

Excel files are stored in azure blob containers. They are downloaded without incident in IE but in Chrome the page displays this message (and in Canary it crashes):

```
This file appears corrupt
```

and provides a link to download it and all is well from that point. I've tried setting the content-type to different excel formats but the result is the same.

Here's the blob code:

```
  MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
  CreateFile(memoryStream, grid);
  memoryStream.Position = 0;
  var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(randomFileName);
  blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
  blockBlob.DeleteIfExists();

  var options = new BlobRequestOptions()
  {
      ServerTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)
   };

   try
   {
            blockBlob.UploadFromStream(memoryStream, null, options);
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
       _logger.Error("Uploading excel file: Error: {0}",  e.Message);
   }


   return new Uri("https://myblobs.blob.core.windows.net/" + "containername/" + randomFileName);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed `blockBlob.SetProperties();`

Try this:

```
   var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(randomFileName);
   blockBlob.DeleteIfExists();
   blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = 
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
   blockBlob.SetProperties(); // This is for commiting changes.
```

Note that for `.xls` files you need to set `content-type` to `application/vnd.ms-excel`.

FYI: If you want to update property values in existing blob you need to fetch the current values, set the property that we want to update and call `SetProperties` on the BLOB.

Example:

```
    blob.FetchAttributes();
    blob.Properties.ContentType = "image/png";
    blob.SetProperties();
```

Comment: @Will Lopez Does it help ?